# permutation such that adding its location to each element creates a new permutation

Tags: combinatorics

For even n, does there exist a permutation of the elements of Z<sub>n</sub> such that adding the location in the permutation to each element of the permutation creates a new permutation?

For example if n is odd instead (n=5):
Consider the permutation 01234, if you add the location in the permutation to each element (the first element being at location 0) you get a new permutation 02413

I don't think this is possible for even n in general however I have only proven this true by exhaustion for a few even n. I would like to know a proof for all even n, or if no proof exists, I'd like a counter example.

Thanks

Here is another example:
<0,2,4,1,3> + <0,1,2,3,4> = <0,3,1,4,2>
notice the first last last vector all have different entries

Comment: To see if I understand: Think of a permutation in list notation (e.g., the identity $(0\ 1)$), and think of that list as a vector (so $(0, 1)$); add that vector to itself (getting $(0, 1) + (0, 1) = (0, 2) \equiv (0, 0) \pmod 2$). Then the question is, is that vector ever a permutation (writing it back in list notation), for even $n$?

Comment: not quite, we are adding any permutation vector to the identity vector (0,1,...n) and asking if we can ever get another permutation vector

Comment: You would need to fix a way to represent permutations. What if the permutation has more than one cycle, for instance $(045)(123)$?

Comment: By permutation I simply mean a list of n elements of `Z<sub>n</sub>` such that no element apears twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then the sum of the elements of $\Bbb Z_n$
is $n/2$. So if you "add" two permutations of $\Bbb Z_n$, then you get a list of
elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ whose sum is zero, and so this list cannot be
a permutation.

Comment: why must a list that sums to 0 not be a permutation?

Comment: Because a permutation sums to $n/2$.